Using `\input` inside documentation (.dtx) files
The different category codes active in .dtx files cause problems with commands that use \input inside them. An example is the \worldflag command from the worldflags package. Comments within included files are ignored during "normal" TeX runs, but inside .dtx files, the comments are interpreted as ordinary text, causing either warnings or errors.
I tried changing the catcode of % before calling \input, but that causes errors, too.
Is there a workaround to this sort of thing, short of changing % to %%, %^^A, or %^^X in files that will be included?

Please can you give a MWE of the issue - I'm not sure it quite makes sense at the moment

{\catcode\%=14 \input{whatever}}` should work

This falls in the category of "things I thought I tried but evidently made a typo doing it"! @DavidCarlisle's suggestion (i.e., \catcode\%=14 \input{whatever}) did indeed work, as I would have expected, but evidently I made a typo the first (several) times I tried to do that. Oddly, using something like \newcommand*{\protectedinput}[1]{{\catcode`%=14 \input{#1}}does *not* work, though using\def` does.

@karlh your newcommand should work if def does, but if you show no code hard to say.

It was a combination of a bunch of typos, evidently...you are correct, \newcommand* works, too.

It is in fact easier to normalize catcodes for input files than for inline arguments (which are tokenized while scanning the argument).
{\catcode`\%=14 \input{whatever}}

Should work.

This solution (which I tried before asking the question) not working for me was a combination of not including the surrounding braces (which obviously has side effects), trying to define it across multiple lines in the .dtx file, each of which starts with % (facepalm), and trying to use something like \newcommand*{\protected@include} without using makeatletter first. (As I said...multiple typos!)
